# useHooks to be used in two different ways

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using hooks to get data from backend. The api gives 2 different results based on a param.
On screen1, I call the hook with no param and get the results.
On screen2, I want to call the same hook but with a param to the same API.

For example, when I am on screen1, I get the employee list (let's say 10 records)
Now, when I navigate to screen2 and call the hook with a param, I expect the api to get executed and give me say 20 records. But, the response data from api call is already available in `employees` from screen1 so the dispatch is not executed again. See the line below.

`if (typeof employees === 'undefined' && !loader)`

To overcome this problem, I thought of using a flag passed to hooks when I am on screen2 and call the api with param. But it ends up in an infinite loop. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Here's my hook:

```
 const useEmployees = param => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const loader = useSelector(getLoader)

  // Fetch all employees
  const employees = useSelector(getEmpList)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof employees === 'undefined' && !loader) {
      dispatch(getEmployees(param))
    }
  }, [param, employees, dispatch, loader])

  return { loader, employees }
}

export default useEmployees
```

Answer (score 0):

Without questioning why `[param, employees, dispatch, loader]` is your list of deps, or why the dispatcher doesn't already solve this problem for you, a solution that's always available is to simply use a ref.

```
const paramRef = React.useRef(param);
// then in the useEffect:
useEffect(() => {
    let paramChanged = false;
    if (param !== paramRef.current) {
        paramRef.current = param; // update the compare value
        paramChanged = true;
    }
    if (paramChanged ...etc) {
    // ...
}, [ ... ])
```

Comment: I tried this solution, it falls again in an infinite loop :-(

Comment: Are you memo'ing your `param`? If not you can trigger an infinite re-render loop. React will warn you about this.

Comment: No, I am not doing useMemo. Is it required?

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is _yes_, but it's probably good that you understand why. There's a lot of documentation for it https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo and I found that once this 'clicks' in your head issues like this become easy to solve. If you're doing async stuff you're going to need a good grasp of memo'ing.

Comment: Here's what I am doing: ```useEffect(() => {
    let paramChanged = false
    if (param !== paramRef.current) {
      paramRef.current = param // update the compare value
      paramChanged = true
    }
    if (paramChanged && !loadingStatus) {
      dispatch(getEmployees(param))
      paramChanged = false
    } else if (typeof employees === 'undefined' && !loadingStatus) {
      dispatch(getEmployees(param)) //here param is undefined 'cos the call does not need a param
    }
  }, [param, employees, dispatch, loadingStatus])```

Comment: No no, you need to memo `param` where you're calling `useEmployees()`.